# struct to byte array [SafeArrayTypeMismatchException]

Tags: c#, marshalling

Error when copying structure in an byte array.

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException**

Structure:

```
public struct fbody
{
    public float left;
    public float right;
    public float bottom;
    public float top;
    public char[] regname;
    public int index;
    public char[] weather;
    public char[] sound;
    public byte[] regcolor;
    public byte endstr;
};
```

Function of record in an array of bytes:

```
private byte[] StructToByteArray(object _oStruct)
{
    byte[] mem = new byte[sizeee];
    IntPtr hmem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeee);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(_oStruct, hmem, false);
    Marshal.Copy(hmem, mem, 0, mem.Length);
    return mem;
}
```

int **sizeee** is global variable, size all data in structure.

Error this line: **Marshal.StructureToPtr(_oStruct, hmem, false);**

Comment: You should consider putting the exception text within your post and not the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```
byte[] getBytes<T>(T str) where T:struct
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
    byte[] arr = new byte[size];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}
```